# describe class versions of primitive type data

Tags: java

please some explain to me this....

Explain why java has class versios of primitive data types? describe the class versions of primitive java types and expain pros and cons? expalin why class versions of primitive java types are available, but why the primitive types are still frequently used? expalin how primitive and non-primitive data types are passed as parameters to methods in java and how that affects altering the value of data passed?

primitve data types are: int, float, char, long, short, byte, boolean and double.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Err, Java AND Javascript? These things have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Copy-pasted homework questions are not usually popular at SO. Perhaps if you gave your own thoughts on the subject you'd get some corrections and additions.

Comment: but i dont understand the concept of java primitve types... thought if someone could be knid enough to guide me a bit on  it.....

Answer (score 2):

For each Java primitive there is a corresponding object:

- `byte` => `java.lang.Byte`
- `short` =>`java.lang.Short`
- `int` =>`java.lang.Integer`
- `long` => `java.lang.Long`
- `float` => `java.lang.Float`
- `double` => `java.lang.Double`
- `char` => `java.lang.Character`
- `boolean` => `java.lang.Boolean`

This question is asking you to justify the existence of these [Java Wrapper Classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) and - having done that - to also justify the existence of the primitive types. When do you use the primitive types and when do you use the Wrapper Classes?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic points.  This is **not a comprehensive list**, just some thoughts to get you started.  Where I talk about integers, the same reasoning works for `double`/`Double`, `char`/`Character`, &c.

- Not the least such reason is simply tradition.  Java was designed to be similar to C/C++ in a number of ways; those languages had similar primitives as their number representations.
- A primitive `int` is lighter — i.e. smaller — than an object `Integer`.  An `Integer` has to contain the same information about the number value as the primitive; in fact, it stores the number in a private `int` variable!  And it has the added baggage of needing to support a number of methods that primitives don't have to deal with.
- A primitive `int` is faster than an object `Integer`.  This is related to the last point; creating an `Integer` object is much more involved behind the scenes than creating a primitive `int` is.
- There are situations when you aren't allowed to use primitives.  If you want to, say, fill up a linked list with numbers, and you decide to use a Java built-in `LinkedList`, it expects you to make the list out of objects.

You would probably benefit from reading up on "autoboxing," "passing by value in Java" and "garbage collection in Java," to name a few topics.  Here's a link to get you started: [the Java Language Specification section on primitives](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2), which is conveniently followed by the section on reference types — i.e. objects.